# Converting number outputs and inputs into words

Tags: java

i had a quick question, so i finished up writing my program which is a simple Rock, Paper Scissors game but at the moment it only displays 0,1,2 which 0 is scissors, 1 is rock, and 2 is paper.  The problem im having is that im not quite sure how to give the users input as well as what the computer outputs go from displaying numbers to displaying scissors, rock, paper.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Lab3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Hello user! lets play ");
        System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Type in 0 for Scissors, 1 for Rock, or 2 for Paper ");
        int userInput = in.nextInt();

        int opponentsHand = (int)(Math.random()*3);




        if (userInput == opponentsHand)
        {

        System.out.print("Darth Vader has played " + opponentsHand);
        System.out.println(" Despite your efforts of playing " + userInput + ", this battle has     ended in a draw!");
    }

    if (userInput < opponentsHand && opponentsHand != 2)
    {
        System.out.print("Darth vader has played "+ opponentsHand);
        System.out.println(", You played " + userInput + "You have Lost");
    }

    else if (userInput < opponentsHand && opponentsHand == 2)
    {
        System.out.print("Darth Vader has played " + opponentsHand);
        System.out.println(" You played " + userInput + " You have won");
    }

    if (userInput > opponentsHand && opponentsHand != 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Darth Vader has played " + opponentsHand);
        System.out.println(" You have played " + userInput + " You have won");
    }

    else if (userInput > opponentsHand && opponentsHand == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Darth Vader has played " + opponentsHand);
        System.out.println(" You have played " + userInput + " You have lost");
    }




}
```

}

thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to simply use an array to store the names of the hands:

```
String[] hands = {"scissors", "rock", "paper"};
```

When you print, you do the following:

```
System.out.print("Darth Vader has played " + hands[opponentsHand]);
```

Comment: wow it works perfectly thank you so much! :) now my program is finally complete thank you once again  btw just curious to know when i stored values into the string how does the program know which number is represented by the Words Rock, Paper, Scissor?

Comment: That's just the sequence of the words appeared in that 'hands' array. Obviously you can adjust, for example, if you want 0 be rock, 1 be scissors and 2 be paper, then just put them in that sequence.